# how to add Augmented Reality concept of vuforia in Android Application through Android Studio

Tags: animation, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

i need to do Augumented Reality based location detection based on mobile device orientation, while detecting location i need the AR to animate the screen based on objects faced while moving..

```
any guidelines welcome, thanks
```

Comment: AR is a large scope subject. There are a lot of libraries, with different properties and different features. Start searching the existing libraries, read what they supply and choose what suits your needs. Then, come back here with specific questions.

Comment: i need to animate the screen while it is face towards one side(east,west,north,south) depending upon the circumstances. during this i need to detect the location and side mobile device is facing towards ....how can i do that in vuforia in Android App???

Comment: This has nothing to do with Vuforia. Vuforia lets you detect pre-defined images. You need to integrate the device sensors - do some reading on accelerometer, gyro etc.

Comment: i need to animate the screen to show the nearby service centers available in the map using vuforia .. thats what i have planned to do.. could u guide me??

Comment: No - Vuforia is not meant for location based AR... Vuforia will only recognize images you have prepared in advance. If you insist on this, you need to integrate another service or switch to another AR SDK...

Comment: ohh kk then can u opt me any AR sdk to build it into android application in android studio??

Answer (score 0):

As it seems, what you need is a geo-location based AR SDK, while Vuforia is a marker-based AR SDK (the detection is based on pre-known images fed to Vuforia database). So, you should look for other SDKs - I think a good place to start would be: [Wikitude](https://www.wikitude.com/). Also, if you want to search further, look at this comparison table, you need the GPS column: [AR SDK Comparison](http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks)

Comment: can i animate the objects in the circumstances everywhere,which it detects?? but i dont have an idea , how to use it in Android studio!!